# background zoom on ipad and iphone

Tags: css

I do not understand why my background is zooming around 1500% in, when I look on my site on an Iphone or Ipad.

The CSS code for my background is here:

```
    html { 
          background-image: 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: left top;
          background-attachment:fixed;
   }
```

**UPDATE after comment**

**Iphone**

[![Iphone][2]][2]

**Ipad**

[![Ipad][3]][3]

**Desktop**
[![Desktop][4]][4]

Comment: Can you give a screen shot? Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have just added the sceenshot of iphone, ipad and the desktop

Comment: The screenshots haven't been added, they seem to be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhones and iPads "have" a screen resolution of 1920 x 1080, did you add these tags to the top of your site:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the comment. I just had the first one, but not the second. I just tried to add your code, but it is still the same.